# What is the improvement of using DAO in Java SE?

Tags: java, testing, dao

My project manager wants me to use DAO/DTO objects to access and retrieve data from database. Project is written in Java SE without using any framework or ORM. His arguments is to make code more testable and to improve code design. Does it make sense?

How about initializing DAO object? Should it be initialized when the instance of class having DAO field is created:

```
private PersonDao personDao = new PersonDaoImpl();
```

or rather initialized when it is necessary?

```
public class A {
  private PersonDao person;

  public List<Person> findAll() {
    person = new PersonDaoImpl();
    return person.getAll();
  }
}
```

It allows to mock this interface easily, but is it right to the DAO pattern usage convention?

Comment: it would be so because using jpa you would not have to write it

Comment: Is he going to ask you to reinvent some ORM in your application? :)

Comment: The argument is that ORM works much slower than JDBC and db performance is very important in that project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To maximimze the benefits of testability and separation of concerns you should introduce the concept of Inversion of Control (IoC). When applying IoC to the management of object lifecycles the term Dependency Injection is used. What this means is that your class A should be completely agnostic of which implementation is instantiated when.

In order to achieve this you need an extra component to bootstrap your application and inject all classes with the correct implementations.

You could set up your dependency-receiving class like this (setter injection, you can also use constructors)

```
public class PersonServiceImpl implements PersonService {

    private PersonDao personDao;

    public List<Person> findAll() {
        return personDao.getAll();
    }

    public setPersonDaoA(PersonDao personDao) {
        this.personDao = personDao;
    }
}
```

And a component to do the dependency injection:

```
public class ApplicationContext {

    private PersonService personService;
    private PersonDao personDao ;

    public PersonService getPersonService() {
        if (personService == null) {
            personService= new PersonServiceImpl();
            personService.setPersonDao(getPersonDao());
        }
        return personService;
    }

    public PersonDao getPersonDao() {
        if (personDao == null) {
            personDao = new PersonDaoIml();
        }
        return personDao ;
    }
}
```

Then application startup would involve this:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = new ApplicationContext();
        PersonService personService = ctx.getPersonService();
        personService.findAll();
    }
}
```

As you can see, the ApplicationContext encapsulates knowlegde about:

- which implementations to use
- in which order to set a chain of dependencies
- which dependencies are already instantiated or not

The PersonServiceImpl class is now completely testable and all concerns regarding object lifecycle management have been extracted from it.

In real life this if often done using a framework like Spring or CDI (which is becoming more and more popular recently). But in your situation, starting off with an approach like above might be a good first step. It will reap the immediate benefits mentioned by your project manager without incurring the overhead of introducing Spring, possibly changing your build too and having to learn how that works (e.g. with an XML context, source code context and/or annotations).

Introducing Spring at a later stage will be easy because all classes are already prepared for Dependency Injection. Just keep in mind that your factory (ApplicationContext in my example) should not take on any extra responsibilities like configuration management.

Also keep in mind that the above example of ApplicationContext is not a singleton. You yourself should make sure only one instance of it is created when your application starts, and all injections are handled by it. Creating duplicate instances could cause confusing bugs.

Answer (score 2):

The Data Access Object is basically an object or an interface that provides access to an underlying database or any other persistence storage.

That definition from: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object

Maybe a simple example can help you understand the concept:

Let's say we have an entity to represent an employee:

```
public class Employee {
private int id;
private String name;
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

The employee entities will be persisted into a corresponding Employee table in a database. A simple DAO interface to handle the database operation required to manipulate an employee entity will be like:

```
interface EmployeeDAO {
List<Employee> findAll();
List<Employee> findById();
List<Employee> findByName();
boolean insertEmployee(Employee employee);
boolean updateEmployee(Employee employee);
boolean deleteEmployee(Employee employee);
}
```

Next we have to provide a concrete implementation for that interface to deal with SQL server, and another to deal with flat files, etc...

Hope that helps

Comment: I what DAO is and how to use it in enterprise environment with DI, but I rather asked if it makes sense to create DAO writing standard Java code and how it should be used to maximize benefits of this pattern. Anyway, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are using it, it is still tightly coupled with your class A.

You should provide your DAO as a dependency, using constructor or setter. Probably the most preferable way is to use some kind of Inversion of Control (for example dependency injection framework).

Your class A should be something like:

```
public class A {
  private PersonDao personDao;

  // possibly an @Inject annotation 
  public A(PersonDao personDao) {
     this.personDao = personDao;
  }

  public List<Person> findAll() {

    return personDao.getAll();
  }
}
```

And actually, I would consider it an antipattern this way. It depends on how you are about to use your class A. 
If it contains different business logic - fine.
If it just dispatches a call to DAO (I don't like this name, maybe use Repository instead ;)) then it is just unnecessary layer of abstraction.

Another thing - you mentioned DTO. So a Person class is just a DTO in this case? Here we could have another antipattern. DTO is fine for example if you need to transform your business object(s) into something that is visible on the screen. Or to separate perstistence model from business model.

What I'm trying to say is: don't make a Person class just a data structure. Give it some behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

The DAO pattern is not an "enterprise" pattern. It's mostly seen in "enterprise" applications, but you can absolutely use in a an application written in SE only.

It's not because you're writing an SE application that you don't have to test, so indeed, your code will be more testable using the DAO pattern and IOC rather than using straight JDBC in your application.

The way you're implementing your class using the DAO is problematic because your class cannot be tested properly because of the tight coupling between your class A and your DAO implementation. You're better off using the IOC pattern as well with a framework like Guice or Dagger (both designed with SE in mind).

For a code example, look at slnowak's answer.